# Grails 3.2.8 deployment : o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper on application startup

Tags: grails

I recently deployed a Grails application to Tomcat and ran into the following exception on startup.

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper
```

Im not sure whats going on. All supporting Domain objects are being created in BootStrap without issue locally, however it fails to create the same supporting data and throws the exception above when BootStrap.groovy go through its routine in production.

Grails version 3.2.8

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that BootStrap data generation was failing because `dbCreate` in the application.yml was set to `none` in production. Simply change `none` to `update`.

Change from:

**application.yml**

```
production:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: none
```

To:

**application.yml**

```
production:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
```

This resolved my issue